# Unity + PlayFab "Namespace Dictionary could not be found"

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use

```
UpdateUserData
```

to add/update Key-Value pairs to a user, but I get this error:

> Assets/PlayFabManager.cs(73,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name `Dictionary' could not be found. Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

I tried following other solutions on google but I couldn't get them to work. How can we get this to work?

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;

public class PlayFabManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public string PlayFabId;

    void Login(string titleId)
    {
        LoginWithCustomIDRequest request = new LoginWithCustomIDRequest()
        {
            TitleId = titleId,
            CreateAccount = true,
            CustomId = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier
        };

        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomID(request, (result) => {
            PlayFabId = result.PlayFabId;
            Debug.Log("Got PlayFabID: " + PlayFabId);

            if(result.NewlyCreated)
            {
                Debug.Log("(new account)");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("(existing account)");
                SetUserData();
                GetUserData();
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            Debug.Log("Error logging in player with custom ID:");
            Debug.Log(error.ErrorMessage);
        });
    }

    void GetUserData()
    {
        GetUserDataRequest request = new GetUserDataRequest()
        {
            PlayFabId = PlayFabId,
            Keys = null
        };

        PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserData(request,(result) => {
            Debug.Log("Got user data:");
            if ((result.Data == null) || (result.Data.Count == 0))
            {
                Debug.Log("No user data available");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log (result.Data["age"].Value);
                foreach (var item in result.Data)
                {
                    Debug.Log("    " + item.Key + " == " + item.Value.Value);
                }
            }
        }, (error) => {
            Debug.Log("Got error retrieving user data:");
            Debug.Log(error.ErrorMessage);
        });
    }

    void SetUserData()
    {
        UpdateUserDataRequest request = new UpdateUserDataRequest()
        {
            Data = new Dictionary(){
                {"Ancestor", "Arthur"},
                {"Successor", "Fred"}
            }
        };

        PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserData(request, (result) =>
                                        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully updated user data");
        }, (error) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Got error setting user data Ancestor to Arthur");
            Debug.Log(error.ErrorDetails);
        });
    }

    void Awake(){
        PlayFabSettings.TitleId = "HIDDEN"; //your title id goes here.
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Login ("HIDDEN");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced

```
    {
        Data = new Dictionary(){
            {"Ancestor", "Arthur"},
            {"Successor", "Fred"}
        }
    };
```

with

```
    request.Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    request.Data.Add("It's over", " 9000!!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
           Dictionary<string, string> Data = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"Ancestor", "Arthur"},
                {"Successor", "Fred"}
             };
​
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it over and I get these 2 errors:

Error #1: "Assets/PlayFabManager.cs(73,55): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type" and Error #2: "Assets/PlayFabManager.cs(76,26): error CS8032: Internal compiler error during parsing, Run with -v for details"

Comment: Right click on UpdateUserDataRequest and select "go to definition).  You need to find out how data is declared in method().  You should be able to replace Data with request.Data.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, request.Data was indeed the route to go.